# Tearraform list down files in GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-storage

I have a gcs bucket with multiple nested parquet files. I want to view the parquet file as **external tables** in BQ.

For example:

```
path1 >> path2 >> path3 >> path4 >> *.parquet
path11 >> path22 >> path33 >> *.parquet
```

Is there a way I can list down the gcs uri using terraform? Then use the `gcs_uri` in the terraform written as such:

```
variable my_table_config {
  default = {
    first_table  = { gcs_path = "path11/path22/path33/*.parquet"}
    second_table = { gcs_path = "path1/path2/path3/path3/path4/*.parquet"}
  }
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "my_dataset" {
   # create table
}


resource "google_bigquery_table" "my_dataset_external_tables" {
  dataset_id  = google_bigquery_dataset.my_dataset.dataset_id
  for_each    = var.my_table_config # start loop here
  table_id    = each.key

  external_data_configuration {
    autodetect    = true
    source_format = "PARQUET"
    ignore_unknown_values = true
    source_uris = [
      "gs://my-gcs-bucket/${(each.value).gcs_path}" # get path of parquet files
    ]
  }
  project = var.project
}
```

The above terraform will work if I have small number of `gcs_uri` (I can append in `my_table_config`). But I have over thousands of `gcs_uri` to do. I'm looking for something to automate to retrieve the gcs_uri. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using wild cards e.g. gsutil ls  gs://bucket_name/*/**.parquet  in cloud shell and then may be you can use a loop in terraform to use all of them one by one?

Comment: Oh yeah. I only considered `*.parquet`, I will give it a try

Comment: If the issue is solved, I would suggest to post it as an answer to help other users that may face this scenario. Thanks!